# Identify Time Spent in Rendering in Swing Application

Tags: java, performance, swing

We have Swing Application and its slow. It fetches data using web services. This data fetching is done by SwingWorker in a separate thread. When data arrives its rendered.

I would like to identify whether fetching data or its rendering is the culprit. Tried profiling with YJP but could not make much headway. Though it identifies time spent in "paint()" method but I think that's not sufficient.

Any pointers to demarcate the boundaries and find time spent in rendering will be appreciated.

How to do performance testing of a swing application ?

Comment: Use a Java profiler..

Comment: Tried a profiler but it does not clearly demarcate the boundaries

Comment: Not `paintComponent()`?